# Export to CSV in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Having a problem where my exported files has an error above the file

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: year in **C:\xampp\htdocs\new1v2\admin\exporttoexcel.php** on line **23**
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: kurs in **C:\xampp\htdocs\new1v2\admin\exporttoexcel.php** on line **25**

but shows the result apparently.

This is my form where I will select either of the three select option:

```
<form method="post" action="exporttoexcel.php">
        <select name="year" style="padding:5px; height:40px;">
                <option disabled selected>--Year Graduated</option>
                <?php
                    $year_grad=1995;
                    while($year_grad<=2017)
                    {
                ?>
                <option>
                    <?php echo $year_grad; ?>
                </option>
                    <?php $year_grad++; } ?>
            </select>
            <select name="deprtmnt" style="padding:5px; height:40px;">
                <option disabled selected>--Department</option>
                <option>College of Computer Studies</option>
            </select>
            <select name="kurs" style="padding:5px; height:40px;">
                <option disabled selected>--Course</option>
                <option>Bachelor of Science in Information Technology</option>
                <option>Bachelor of Science in Computer Studies</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="w3-btn w3-green"><font size="6"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Export to CSV</font></button>
    </form>
```

It is year, kurs and deprtment. 
and this is part of my exporttoexcel.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$year = $_POST['year'];

$kurs =  $_POST['kurs'];

$dept = $_POST['deprtmnt'];

$search_str= '';
        if ($year){
            $search_str .= $search_str ? ' AND ': 'WHERE' ;
            $search_str .= "`tblalumni`.`yeargrad` LIKE '%" .$year."%' "; 
        }
        if ($dept){
            $search_str .= $search_str ? ' AND ': 'WHERE' ;
            $search_str .= "`tblalumni`.`department` LIKE '%" .$dept."%' "; 
        }
        if ($kurs){
            $search_str .= $search_str ? ' AND ': 'WHERE' ;
            $search_str .= "`tblalumni`.`course` LIKE '%" .$kurs."%' "; 
        }


$output         = "";
$table          = "tblalumni"; // Enter Your Table Name
$sql            = mysql_query("SELECT fname as 'First Name', mname as 'Middle Name', lname as 'Last Name', yeargrad as 'Year Graduated', department as 'Department'  FROM tblAlumni {$search_str}  AND alum_status = 2");
```

The feature is that either of the three selected it will show the query.

How to remove the error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the value in the `<option>` tag for the select box. That's why php cannot get the value.

Add the value to option tag like this:

**$year**

```
<option selected value="">--Year Graduated</option>

<option value="<?php echo $year_grad;">
    <?php echo $year_grad; ?>
 </option>
```

**$dept**

```
<select name="deprtmnt" style="padding:5px; height:40px;">
      <option selected value="">--Department</option>
       <option value="College of Computer Studies">College of Computer Studies</option>
</select>
```

**$kurs**

```
<select name="kurs" style="padding:5px; height:40px;">
       <option selected value="">--Course</option>
       <option value="Bachelor of Science in Information Technology">Bachelor of Science in Information Technology</option>
       <option value="Bachelor of Science in Computer Studies">Bachelor of Science in Computer Studies</option>
</select>
```

Next in your PHP, modify the get input code like this:

```
$year = (isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year'] : "";

$kurs =  (isset($_POST['kurs']) ? $_POST['kurs'] : "";

$dept= (isset($_POST['dprtmnt']) ? $_POST['dprtmnt'] : "";
```

And in your if else code do checking like this:

```
if($year != ''){
    // do your code here
}
if ($dept != ''){
    // do your code here
}
if ($kurs != ''){
    // do your code here
}
```

REMEMBER, if the PHP throw "Undefined index" errors, that's mean PHP cannot access the value for the variable, the variable value is "undefined".

Comment: yes, I know. Because the feature is in the 3 select option you can select 1 without selecting the others.

Comment: You cannot do it like that LOL. You still need to set the value. And in the first ```<option>``` tag, remove the ```disabled``` attribute. That way, if the user does not choose the select box, the value that will be send is null. So next in php for the if else code you need to check ```if ($year != ''){ //code }```